# ES6-style Export-from in Typescript Module Definition (module.d.ts)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

To be honest, I have very little idea what is actually happening. I am trying to create a declaration file based on the one shown [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-class-d-ts.html) - something I have never done before.

I have these files (renamed and edited due to work rules):

**project_one**

*some_interface.ts*

```
import SomeOtherInterface from "some_other_file";

interface ThisInterface
{
  aMethodRequiring(aThing: SomeOtherInterface): void;
}

export default ThisInterface;
```

*index.d.ts*

```
export { default as ThisInterface } from "some_interface";
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.type.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

**project_two**

*some_class.ts*

```
/// <reference types="project_one" />
     /* ^ This seems to be fine ^ */

import SomethingInThisProject from "a_file_in_this_project";
import { ThisInterface }      from "project_one"; // <=== This is the line that fails.

class ThatClass
{
  private instanceOfThisInterface : ThisInterface;

  constructor(saidInstance: ThisInterface)
  {
    this.instanceOfThisInterface = saidInstance;
  }

  // The useful stuff
}

export default ThatClass;
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.type.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "project_two",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Second Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/project/two",
  "author": "Cyle Ven Dawson",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "project_one": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

TypeScript finds the **project_one** declaration file just fine. However, it yells at me about the `import`ing from it, saying `[ts] cannot find module 'project_one'.` I imagine there is more wrong with this code than simply how I try to import things from the declaration file, but for now I am looking to get the `import` line to work.

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: Can you shows us the package.json? Is `project_one` properly registered as a dependency of `project_two`?

Comment: @E_net4 Added the package.json contents. `project_one` is set as a dependency as shown.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the custom typing should be referenced in the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
            "./custom_typings",
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ]
    }
}
```

See tsconfig [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) for more detailed information.

Comment: TypeScript seems to find the declarations just fine. In my editor, I can use the "go to" feature to hop to the declaration file within the `project_one` directory under `node_modules`. The error is not on the `references` line, but rather the `import { ThisInterface } ...` line.

Comment: For the sake of knowing if you can import anything  at all from `project_one`, does the following line work: `import  * as project_one from "project_one"` ?

Comment: Just tried it - got the same `[ts] Cannot find module 'project_one'.` error.

Comment: This may seem far-fetched but if you are using vscode try reloading the project. Sometimes it doesn't pick up config changes.

Comment: Okay, no change there, either. Running the compiler myself yields the same error, except instead of `[ts]` it shows `error TS2307:`, but I assume that error code does not tell us much else.

Comment: Try specifying the module resolution in the tsconfig if you haven't done already:   "compilerOptions": {  "moduleResolution": "node"  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148563/discussion-between-guwere-and-dawsonc623).